# Kafka segments are deleted too often or not at all

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

We have two topics on our Kafka cluster that exhibit weird (wrong) behavior related to retention configuration.

One topic, **tracking.ap.client.traffic**, has retention set explicitly to "retention.ms=14400000" (4 hrs) - but it is not cleaned up , grows in size, and caused 2 out of 3 kafka brokers to run out of disk space. (details about config and log below)

Second topic, **tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed**, is created in KSQL as a stream topic:

```
CREATE STREAM AP_CLIENT_TRAFFIC_KEYED
    WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed', TIMESTAMP='ACTIVITY_DATE', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON', PARTITIONS=6)
    AS SELECT
...
```

its retention is set to the default broker value, which is 720 hrs :

```
cat /etc/kafka/server.properties | grep retention
log.retention.hours=720
# A size-based retention policy for logs. Segments are pruned from the log unless the remaining
# segments drop below log.retention.bytes. Functions independently of log.retention.hours.
#log.retention.bytes=1073741824
# to the retention policies
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
```

This topic, though, gets cleaned up every 5 min or so - according to the logs....
The log entry says the segment is marked for deletion "due to retention time 2592000000ms breach (kafka.log.Log)" - but how can that be true if this is happening every 5 min??

No size-based retention is set for any of the topics.

Two questions:

1. why is the first topic not being cleaned p?
2. why is the second topic being cleaned up so often?

Below are the details about logs and full config of both topics:

log entries for **tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed**-2 topic/partition - show that this partition is getting cleaned too often:

```
[2021-05-19 21:35:05,822] INFO [Log partition=tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-2, dir=/apps/kafka-data] Incrementing log start offset to 11755700 (kafka.log.Log)
[2021-05-19 21:36:05,822] INFO [Log partition=tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-2, dir=/apps/kafka-data] Deleting segment 11753910 (kafka.log.Log)
[2021-05-19 21:36:05,825] INFO Deleted log /apps/kafka-data/tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-2/00000000000011753910.log.deleted. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
[2021-05-19 21:36:05,827] INFO Deleted offset index /apps/kafka-data/tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-2/00000000000011753910.index.deleted. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
[2021-05-19 21:36:05,829] INFO Deleted time index /apps/kafka-data/tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-2/00000000000011753910.timeindex.deleted. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
[2021-05-19 21:40:05,838] INFO [Log partition=tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-2, dir=/apps/kafka-data] Found deletable segments with base offsets [11755700] due to retention time 2592000000ms breach (kafka.log.Log)
[2021-05-19 21:40:05,843] INFO [ProducerStateManager partition=tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-2] Writing producer snapshot at offset 11757417 (kafka.log.ProducerStateManager)
[2021-05-19 21:40:05,845] INFO [Log partition=tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-2, dir=/apps/kafka-data] Rolled new log segment at offset 11757417 in 7 ms. (kafka.log.Log)
[2021-05-19 21:40:05,845] INFO [Log partition=tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-2, dir=/apps/kafka-data] Scheduling log segment [baseOffset 11755700, size 936249] for deletion. (kafka.log.Log)
[2021-05-19 21:40:05,847] INFO [Log partition=tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-2, dir=/apps/kafka-data] Incrementing log start offset to 11757417 (kafka.log.Log)
[2021-05-19 21:41:05,848] INFO [Log partition=tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-2, dir=/apps/kafka-data] Deleting segment 11755700 (kafka.log.Log)
[2021-05-19 21:41:05,850] INFO Deleted log /apps/kafka-data/tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-2/00000000000011755700.log.deleted. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
[2021-05-19 21:41:05,852] INFO Deleted offset index /apps/kafka-data/tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-2/00000000000011755700.index.deleted. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
[2021-05-19 21:41:05,853] INFO Deleted time index /apps/kafka-data/tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-2/00000000000011755700.timeindex.deleted. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
[2021-05-19 21:45:05,834] INFO [Log partition=tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-2, dir=/apps/kafka-data] Found deletable segments with base offsets [11757417] due to retention time 2592000000ms breach (kafka.log.Log)
[2021-05-19 21:45:05,837] INFO [ProducerStateManager partition=tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-2] Writing producer snapshot at offset 11759201 (kafka.log.ProducerStateManager)
[2021-05-19 21:45:05,839] INFO [Log partition=tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-2, dir=/apps/kafka-data] Rolled new log segment at offset 11759201 in 6 ms. (kafka.log.Log)
[2021-05-19 21:45:05,839] INFO [Log partition=tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-2, dir=/apps/kafka-data] Scheduling log segment [baseOffset 11757417, size 977444] for deletion. (kafka.log.Log)
[2021-05-19 21:45:05,842] INFO [Log partition=tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-2, dir=/apps/kafka-data] Incrementing log start offset to 11759201 (kafka.log.Log)
[2021-05-19 21:46:05,842] INFO [Log partition=tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-2, dir=/apps/kafka-data] Deleting segment 11757417 (kafka.log.Log)
[2021-05-19 21:46:05,844] INFO Deleted log /apps/kafka-data/tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-2/00000000000011757417.log.deleted. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
[2021-05-19 21:46:05,845] INFO Deleted offset index /apps/kafka-data/tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-2/00000000000011757417.index.deleted. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
[2021-05-19 21:46:05,847] INFO Deleted time index /apps/kafka-data/tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-2/00000000000011757417.timeindex.deleted. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
[2021-05-19 21:50:05,832] INFO [Log partition=tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-2, dir=/apps/kafka-data] Found deletable segments with base offsets [11759201] due to retention time 2592000000ms breach (kafka.log.Log)
[2021-05-19 21:50:05,837] INFO [ProducerStateManager partition=tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-2] Writing producer snapshot at offset 11760980 (kafka.log.ProducerStateManager)
[2021-05-19 21:50:05,839] INFO [Log partition=tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-2, dir=/apps/kafka-data] Rolled new log segment at offset 11760980 in 7 ms. (kafka.log.Log)
[2021-05-19 21:50:05,839] INFO [Log partition=tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-2, dir=/apps/kafka-data] Scheduling log segment [baseOffset 11759201, size 991447] for deletion. (kafka.log.Log)
[2021-05-19 21:50:05,844] INFO [Log partition=tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-2, dir=/apps/kafka-data] Incrementing log start offset to 11760980 (kafka.log.Log)
[2021-05-19 21:51:05,844] INFO [Log partition=tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-2, dir=/apps/kafka-data] Deleting segment 11759201 (kafka.log.Log)
[2021-05-19 21:51:05,846] INFO Deleted log /apps/kafka-data/tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-2/00000000000011759201.log.deleted. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
[2021-05-19 21:51:05,848] INFO Deleted offset index /apps/kafka-data/tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-2/00000000000011759201.index.deleted. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
[2021-05-19 21:51:05,849] INFO Deleted time index /apps/kafka-data/tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-2/00000000000011759201.timeindex.deleted. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
[2021-05-19 21:55:05,828] INFO [Log partition=tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-2, dir=/apps/kafka-data] Found deletable segments with base offsets [11760980] due to retention time 2592000000ms breach (kafka.log.Log)
[2021-05-19 21:55:05,833] INFO [ProducerStateManager partition=tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-2] Writing producer snapshot at offset 11762941 (kafka.log.ProducerStateManager)
[2021-05-19 21:55:05,835] INFO [Log partition=tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-2, dir=/apps/kafka-data] Rolled new log segment at offset 11762941 in 7 ms. (kafka.log.Log)
[2021-05-19 21:55:05,835] INFO [Log partition=tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-2, dir=/apps/kafka-data] Scheduling log segment [baseOffset 11760980, size 1079204] for deletion. (kafka.log.Log)
[2021-05-19 21:55:05,838] INFO [Log partition=tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-2, dir=/apps/kafka-data] Incrementing log start offset to 11762941 (kafka.log.Log)
[2021-05-19 21:56:05,838] INFO [Log partition=tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-2, dir=/apps/kafka-data] Deleting segment 11760980 (kafka.log.Log)
[2021-05-19 21:56:05,840] INFO Deleted log /apps/kafka-data/tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-2/00000000000011760980.log.deleted. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
[2021-05-19 21:56:05,842] INFO Deleted offset index /apps/kafka-data/tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-2/00000000000011760980.index.deleted. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
[2021-05-19 21:56:05,843] INFO Deleted time index /apps/kafka-data/tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-2/00000000000011760980.timeindex.deleted. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
```

There are **no such entries** for log cleaning for the first topic, tracking.ap.client.traffic, which indicates it is never even checked for hitting retention ??

Full config for **tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed** topic: (that is cleaned up too often):

```
mac-lt-mpopova:confluent-6.1.0 mpopova$ ./bin/kafka-configs --bootstrap-server mybroker1:9092 --entity-type topics --entity-name tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed --describe --all

All configs for topic tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed are:
  compression.type=producer sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:compression.type=producer}
  leader.replication.throttled.replicas= sensitive=false synonyms={}
  message.downconversion.enable=true sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.message.downconversion.enable=true}
  min.insync.replicas=2 sensitive=false synonyms={STATIC_BROKER_CONFIG:min.insync.replicas=2, DEFAULT_CONFIG:min.insync.replicas=1}
  segment.jitter.ms=0 sensitive=false synonyms={}
  cleanup.policy=delete sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.cleanup.policy=delete}
  flush.ms=9223372036854775807 sensitive=false synonyms={}
  follower.replication.throttled.replicas= sensitive=false synonyms={}
  segment.bytes=1073741824 sensitive=false synonyms={STATIC_BROKER_CONFIG:log.segment.bytes=1073741824, DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.segment.bytes=1073741824}
  retention.ms=2592000000 sensitive=false synonyms={}
  flush.messages=9223372036854775807 sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.flush.interval.messages=9223372036854775807}
  message.format.version=2.1-IV2 sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.message.format.version=2.1-IV2}
  file.delete.delay.ms=60000 sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.segment.delete.delay.ms=60000}
  max.message.bytes=1000012 sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:message.max.bytes=1000012}
  min.compaction.lag.ms=0 sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.cleaner.min.compaction.lag.ms=0}
  message.timestamp.type=CreateTime sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.message.timestamp.type=CreateTime}
  preallocate=false sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.preallocate=false}
  min.cleanable.dirty.ratio=0.5 sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.cleaner.min.cleanable.ratio=0.5}
  index.interval.bytes=4096 sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.index.interval.bytes=4096}
  unclean.leader.election.enable=false sensitive=false synonyms={STATIC_BROKER_CONFIG:unclean.leader.election.enable=false, DEFAULT_CONFIG:unclean.leader.election.enable=false}
  retention.bytes=-1 sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.retention.bytes=-1}
  delete.retention.ms=86400000 sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms=86400000}
  segment.ms=604800000 sensitive=false synonyms={}
  message.timestamp.difference.max.ms=9223372036854775807 sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.message.timestamp.difference.max.ms=9223372036854775807}
  segment.index.bytes=10485760 sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.index.size.max.bytes=10485760}
```

Full config for **tracking.ap.client.traffic** topic: (not being cleaned up at all):

```
mac-lt-mpopova:confluent-6.1.0 mpopova$ ./bin/kafka-configs --bootstrap-server mybroker1:9092 --entity-type topics --entity-name tracking.ap.client.traffic --describe --all

All configs for topic tracking.ap.client.traffic are:
  compression.type=producer sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:compression.type=producer}
  leader.replication.throttled.replicas= sensitive=false synonyms={}
  message.downconversion.enable=true sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.message.downconversion.enable=true}
  min.insync.replicas=2 sensitive=false synonyms={STATIC_BROKER_CONFIG:min.insync.replicas=2, DEFAULT_CONFIG:min.insync.replicas=1}
  segment.jitter.ms=0 sensitive=false synonyms={}
  cleanup.policy=delete sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.cleanup.policy=delete}
  flush.ms=9223372036854775807 sensitive=false synonyms={}
  follower.replication.throttled.replicas= sensitive=false synonyms={}
  segment.bytes=1073741824 sensitive=false synonyms={STATIC_BROKER_CONFIG:log.segment.bytes=1073741824, DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.segment.bytes=1073741824}
  retention.ms=14400000 sensitive=false synonyms={DYNAMIC_TOPIC_CONFIG:retention.ms=14400000}
  flush.messages=9223372036854775807 sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.flush.interval.messages=9223372036854775807}
  message.format.version=2.1-IV2 sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.message.format.version=2.1-IV2}
  file.delete.delay.ms=60000 sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.segment.delete.delay.ms=60000}
  max.message.bytes=1000012 sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:message.max.bytes=1000012}
  min.compaction.lag.ms=0 sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.cleaner.min.compaction.lag.ms=0}
  message.timestamp.type=CreateTime sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.message.timestamp.type=CreateTime}
  preallocate=false sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.preallocate=false}
  min.cleanable.dirty.ratio=0.5 sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.cleaner.min.cleanable.ratio=0.5}
  index.interval.bytes=4096 sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.index.interval.bytes=4096}
  unclean.leader.election.enable=false sensitive=false synonyms={STATIC_BROKER_CONFIG:unclean.leader.election.enable=false, DEFAULT_CONFIG:unclean.leader.election.enable=false}
  retention.bytes=-1 sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.retention.bytes=-1}
  delete.retention.ms=86400000 sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms=86400000}
  segment.ms=604800000 sensitive=false synonyms={}
  message.timestamp.difference.max.ms=9223372036854775807 sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.message.timestamp.difference.max.ms=9223372036854775807}
  segment.index.bytes=10485760 sensitive=false synonyms={DEFAULT_CONFIG:log.index.size.max.bytes=10485760}
```

Here is an example directory content of the logs for both topics:

ls -la /apps/kafka-data/**tracking.ap.client.traffic**-*

```
    /apps/kafka-data/tracking.ap.client.traffic-1:
    total 412640
    drwxr-xr-x   2 cp-kafka confluent       141 May 17 15:01 .
    drwxr-xr-x 290 cp-kafka confluent     20480 May 19 22:48 ..
    -rw-r--r--   1 cp-kafka confluent  10485760 May 19 22:48 00000000000000000000.index
    -rw-r--r--   1 cp-kafka confluent 420599482 May 19 22:48 00000000000000000000.log
    -rw-r--r--   1 cp-kafka confluent  10485756 May 19 22:48 00000000000000000000.timeindex
    -rw-r--r--   1 cp-kafka confluent         8 May 17 15:01 leader-epoch-checkpoint
    
    /apps/kafka-data/tracking.ap.client.traffic-11:
    total 412844
    drwxr-xr-x   2 cp-kafka confluent       141 May 17 11:25 .
    drwxr-xr-x 290 cp-kafka confluent     20480 May 19 22:48 ..
    -rw-r--r--   1 cp-kafka confluent  10485760 May 19 22:48 00000000000000000000.index
    -rw-r--r--   1 cp-kafka confluent 420788365 May 19 22:48 00000000000000000000.log
    -rw-r--r--   1 cp-kafka confluent  10485756 May 19 22:48 00000000000000000000.timeindex
    -rw-r--r--   1 cp-kafka confluent         8 May 17 11:25 leader-epoch-checkpoint
    
    /apps/kafka-data/tracking.ap.client.traffic-13:
    total 412660
    drwxr-xr-x   2 cp-kafka confluent       141 May 17 15:01 .
    drwxr-xr-x 290 cp-kafka confluent     20480 May 19 22:48 ..
    -rw-r--r--   1 cp-kafka confluent  10485760 May 19 22:48 00000000000000000000.index
    -rw-r--r--   1 cp-kafka confluent 420606307 May 19 22:48 00000000000000000000.log
    -rw-r--r--   1 cp-kafka confluent  10485756 May 19 22:48 00000000000000000000.timeindex
    -rw-r--r--   1 cp-kafka confluent         8 May 17 15:01 leader-epoch-checkpoint
    
    /apps/kafka-data/tracking.ap.client.traffic-14:
    total 412920
    drwxr-xr-x   2 cp-kafka confluent       141 May 17 11:25 .
    drwxr-xr-x 290 cp-kafka confluent     20480 May 19 22:48 ..
    -rw-r--r--   1 cp-kafka confluent  10485760 May 19 22:48 00000000000000000000.index
    -rw-r--r--   1 cp-kafka confluent 420862000 May 19 22:48 00000000000000000000.log
    -rw-r--r--   1 cp-kafka confluent  10485756 May 19 22:48 00000000000000000000.timeindex
    -rw-r--r--   1 cp-kafka confluent         8 May 17 11:25 leader-epoch-checkpoint
```

ls -la /apps/kafka-data/**tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed***

```
    /apps/kafka-data/tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-1:
    total 288
    drwxr-xr-x   2 cp-kafka confluent      141 May 19 22:47 .
    drwxr-xr-x 290 cp-kafka confluent    20480 May 19 22:48 ..
    -rw-r--r--   1 cp-kafka confluent 10485760 May 19 22:48 00000000000004255431.index
    -rw-r--r--   1 cp-kafka confluent   254355 May 19 22:48 00000000000004255431.log
    -rw-r--r--   1 cp-kafka confluent 10485756 May 19 22:48 00000000000004255431.timeindex
    -rw-r--r--   1 cp-kafka confluent       14 May 19 22:47 leader-epoch-checkpoint
    
    /apps/kafka-data/tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-2:
    total 816
    drwxr-xr-x   2 cp-kafka confluent      178 May 19 22:46 .
    drwxr-xr-x 290 cp-kafka confluent    20480 May 19 22:48 ..
    -rw-r--r--   1 cp-kafka confluent 10485760 May 19 22:48 00000000000011782064.index
    -rw-r--r--   1 cp-kafka confluent   787175 May 19 22:48 00000000000011782064.log
    -rw-r--r--   1 cp-kafka confluent       10 May 19 22:45 00000000000011782064.snapshot
    -rw-r--r--   1 cp-kafka confluent 10485756 May 19 22:48 00000000000011782064.timeindex
    -rw-r--r--   1 cp-kafka confluent       15 May 19 22:45 leader-epoch-checkpoint
    
    /apps/kafka-data/tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-3:
    total 1812
    drwxr-xr-x   2 cp-kafka confluent      141 May 19 22:47 .
    drwxr-xr-x 290 cp-kafka confluent    20480 May 19 22:48 ..
    -rw-r--r--   1 cp-kafka confluent 10485760 May 19 22:48 00000000000028393394.index
    -rw-r--r--   1 cp-kafka confluent  1814528 May 19 22:48 00000000000028393394.log
    -rw-r--r--   1 cp-kafka confluent 10485756 May 19 22:48 00000000000028393394.timeindex
    -rw-r--r--   1 cp-kafka confluent       15 May 19 22:47 leader-epoch-checkpoint
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Posting my own answer here - after I figured out the reasons for both issues - for the benefit of others who might run into the same problems.

**Problem 1: one topic was not getting cleaned up for a very long time**, even though its retention was set to 4 hrs and there was no limit set for retention.bytes

**Solution/ Reason:**
This issue was rather straightforward to troubleshoot once I came upon a great post from DataDog - with tips on low-volume topics (which is what my topic is): https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/kafka-at-datadog/#why-the-default-segment-level-retention-period-caused-issues-for-our-low-throughput-topic

Specifically, this part was the key:

> Kafka closes a segment and opens a new one when one of two things happens (whichever comes first):

> -- the segment reaches a maximum size (as determined by segment.bytes)
>
> -- the segment-level retention period has passed (based on segment.ms)

Since all segment-level retention settings had default values: (1G and 7days):

```
segment.bytes=1073741824
segment.ms=604800000
```

the events were being accumulated in the segments for a very long time - till either they hit 7 days (which is what happened) or 1G (which did not happen in 7 days) - and only then the cleaner thread was finally picking the segments up as you can see in the logs below:

```
$ cat /var/log/kafka/server.log | grep "Deleted log /apps/kafka-data/tracking.ap.client.traffic-*" | grep -v keyed
[2021-05-24 16:14:16,505] INFO Deleted log /apps/kafka-data/tracking.ap.client.traffic-12/00000000000000000000.log.deleted. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
[2021-05-24 16:14:16,507] INFO Deleted log /apps/kafka-data/tracking.ap.client.traffic-10/00000000000000000000.log.deleted. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
[2021-05-24 16:14:16,530] INFO Deleted log /apps/kafka-data/tracking.ap.client.traffic-6/00000000000000000000.log.deleted. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
[2021-05-24 16:14:16,555] INFO Deleted log /apps/kafka-data/tracking.ap.client.traffic-0/00000000000000000000.log.deleted. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
[2021-05-24 16:14:16,568] INFO Deleted log /apps/kafka-data/tracking.ap.client.traffic-4/00000000000000000000.log.deleted. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
[2021-05-24 16:14:43,717] INFO Deleted log /apps/kafka-data/tracking.ap.client.traffic-14/00000000000000000000.log.deleted. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
[2021-05-24 16:14:43,736] INFO Deleted log /apps/kafka-data/tracking.ap.client.traffic-8/00000000000000000000.log.deleted. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
[2021-05-24 16:14:43,746] INFO Deleted log /apps/kafka-data/tracking.ap.client.traffic-9/00000000000000000000.log.deleted. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
[2021-05-24 16:14:43,756] INFO Deleted log /apps/kafka-data/tracking.ap.client.traffic-3/00000000000000000000.log.deleted. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
[2021-05-24 16:14:43,770] INFO Deleted log /apps/kafka-data/tracking.ap.client.traffic-2/00000000000000000000.log.deleted. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
[2021-05-31 22:04:43,703] INFO Deleted log /apps/kafka-data/tracking.ap.client.traffic-0/00000000000001002122.log.deleted. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
[2021-05-31 22:04:43,748] INFO Deleted log /apps/kafka-data/tracking.ap.client.traffic-14/00000000000000744547.log.deleted. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
[2021-05-31 22:04:43,756] INFO Deleted log /apps/kafka-data/tracking.ap.client.traffic-12/00000000000001002121.log.deleted. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
[2021-05-31 22:04:43,765] INFO Deleted log /apps/kafka-data/tracking.ap.client.traffic-9/00000000000000744551.log.deleted. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
[2021-05-31 22:04:43,771] INFO Deleted log /apps/kafka-data/tracking.ap.client.traffic-8/00000000000000744547.log.deleted. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
[2021-05-31 22:04:43,793] INFO Deleted log /apps/kafka-data/tracking.ap.client.traffic-10/00000000000001002123.log.deleted. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
[2021-05-31 22:04:43,805] INFO Deleted log /apps/kafka-data/tracking.ap.client.traffic-2/00000000000000744547.log.deleted. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
[2021-05-31 22:04:43,815] INFO Deleted log /apps/kafka-data/tracking.ap.client.traffic-3/00000000000000744551.log.deleted. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
[2021-05-31 22:04:43,817] INFO Deleted log /apps/kafka-data/tracking.ap.client.traffic-4/00000000000001002126.log.deleted. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
[2021-05-31 22:04:43,819] INFO Deleted log /apps/kafka-data/tracking.ap.client.traffic-6/00000000000001002124.log.deleted. (kafka.log.LogSegment)
```

Why this was not happening/noticed before:
It is because in the latest release, along with other changes, I have also increased the number of partitions in this topic, from 4 to 15:
with 4 partitions - segments were getting more data quicker, and were rotating once in 1-2 days; with 15 partitions - each partition was getting less data and we were retaining 15x1G of data on average, instead of 4x1G :-)

So, the solution to this issue is to reduce the segment size to something more reasonable for our topic - 100-200M

**Problem 2:** another topic, tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed, created in KSQL, is **cleaned up every 5 min** even though its retention is set to 720hrs and the size of the logs is not reaching its max (1G)

**Solution/ Reason**:
This was a bit more challenging to figure out! What helped me to troubleshoot this was a tip from Matthias Sax on the Kafka user group list: "*Kafka's retention policy is a little bit tricky, because it determines if data is subject to deletion by comparing the **embedded record
timestamps** to the broker wall-clock time*"

I have checked the content of the segments in the topic - and noticed that the "CreatedTime" attribute of the events was set to suspiciously short values:

```
$ /usr/bin/kafka-dump-log --print-data-log --files /apps/kafka-data/tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed-1/00000000000004735501.log | tail -2

offset: 4736628 position: 676217 CreateTime: 1622043813 isvalid: true keysize: 8 valuesize: 506 magic: 2 compresscodec: NONE producerId: -1 producerEpoch: -1 sequence: -1 isTransactional: false headerKeys: [] key: 17606499 payload: {"ACTIVITY_DATE":1622043813001, ...}
offset: 4736629 position: 676801 CreateTime: 1622043814 isvalid: true keysize: 7 valuesize: 425 magic: 2 compresscodec: NONE producerId: -1 producerEpoch: -1 sequence: -1 isTransactional: false headerKeys: [] key: 1229867 payload: {"ACTIVITY_DATE":1622043814001, ...}

$ date
Wed May 26 11:43:40 EDT 2021
```

So, here, "CreateTime: 1622043814" - is in a **wrong format: seconds, instead of  milliseconds!** Why does it matter? because Kafka assumes that the values are in milliseconds, and, if this value is interpreted as milliseconds, the unix timestamp becomes "Mon Jan 19 1970 18:34:03" ! 51 years old events ...
No wonder evens were cleaned up every time the cleaner thread woke up (every 5 min) - since all events in the current segment were 51 years old.

To add a bit more explanation of why this happened .... This topic was created by (via) KSQL, as:

```
CREATE STREAM AP_CLIENT_TRAFFIC_KEYED
WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='tracking.ap.client.traffic.keyed', TIMESTAMP='ACTIVITY_DATE', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON', PARTITIONS=6)
AS SELECT ...
```

where ACTIVITY_DATE is a field in the incoming events, populated by Logstash, in seconds (not sure why seconds - but that's what it is as of now)

So, the solution here is obvious - fix the timestamp :)

Comment: I can honestly say that my jaw dropped reading the second point's solution!
I've setup a Kafka cluster and while troubleshooting why not all data is sent (via a Kafka Connect connector) to the sink destination, long story short I found that data was cleaned up way too quickly...